# how to Target an option from pull down with js to apply more code

Tags: javascript

a friend asked me to help him with a form, a client of his wants to make a form a bit more dynamic...my javascript is minimal at best since i just started learning.

He asked me something along the lines of " how can i make a form show another pull down ONLY WHEN a certain option is selected "

in the example he gave me, by default when page loads,he has a pull down menu which has 2 options, MANHATTAN and option two is BROOKLYN.

If Manhattan is chose, that reveals another pull down with zips for manhattan, if Brooklyn is chosen the same for BK.

in sample html, something along the lines like this:

```
<div>

<form>
    <select name="boro" id="boro">
        <option value="manhattan" id="manh">Manhattan</option>
        <option value="brooklyn" id="brook">Brooklyn</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br/>

<div id="empty2fill"></div><!-- for showing chosen results -->

</div>
```

i want to target/capture the option chosen by the user above on the pull down menu, to then activate this function(below).

according to his request what i guess id do is,(as a newbie), then as far as the .js goes (pseudo code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valBoro (){
    if( brook is chosen){ document.getElementById('empty2fill').innerHTML=" new dropdown code here")

    }

}

</script>
```

aside from not knowing, my main problem is i dont know how to target the option chosen in the menu to thereafter, apply the function (which will be written later)

any ideas, tips etc are greately appreciated.
thanks in advance

Comment: Is the use of jQuery or another JS framework allowed?

Comment: umm id prefer something i can write myself since im learning, the only thing i could do with a library is copy/paste lol

Comment: but hey if thats all you got, or a link or whatever, let me know ill look at it all the same. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to create the two dropdown lists and set the style display to "none". Then you can catch the onChange event and set display to "" based on the value of the select element.

```
function showZip() {
    var boro = document.getElementById("boro");
    if (boro.value == "manhattan") {
        var zipManhattan = document.getElementById("zipManhattan");
        zipManhattan.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

And in the html

```
<div>
    <select name="boro" id="boro" onchange="javascript:showZip();">
        <option value="manhattan" id="manh">Manhattan</option>
        <option value="brooklyn" id="brook">Brooklyn</option>
    </select>

    <br/>

    <select name="zipManhattan" id="zipManhattan" style="display:none;">
        <option value="zip1" id="zip1">1111</option>
        <option value="zip2" id="zip2">2222</option>
    </select>

    <div id="empty2fill"></div><!-- for showing chosen results -->
</div>
```

Comment: The only thing is, do you need the `javascript:` part when you're doing inline event handlers? I thought that was only when you were putting JS in an anchor's `href`.

Comment: i took this one cause it was the simplest lol. others work too but since im a noob. this made more/easier sense to me. i took it, put it in external file and yeah.........thank you

Comment: @somdow - as a "noob" you should learn early how to bind event handlers to DOM elements, rather than using inline event handlers. "[Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)" is a strategy you can use at all levels of programming. For me in this context, it means keeping the HTML structure, the CSS (view-)styling, and the JS behavior separate from each other.

Answer (score 1):

You want to handle the `change` event of your "boro" select element.

I've put a plain-JS example solution on jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/FHArd/1/

This creates three `select` lists - one is your "boro" and the other two are the zip code lists, but they are hidden via CSS until a selection is made.

The `change` event handler simply adds and/or removes classes from the zip code select elements; the CSS hides or shows the lists based on the class "active" that is attached to the zip code select list.

Note - being there in jsfiddle the way you start things up is a little different than normal. You'd really run your setup function at the `onload` or `ondomready` event.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a jsfiddle showing example code.

http://jsfiddle.net/WKqth/

Example markup:

```
<div>

<form>
    <select name="boro" id="boro">
        <option value="" id="none">Select a boro.</option>
        <option value="manhattan" id="manh">Manhattan</option>
        <option value="brooklyn" id="brook">Brooklyn</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br/>

<div id="empty2fill"></div><!-- for showing chosen results -->

</div>
```

Example js

```
// include this js below the form in the body, or wrap it in a function and assign that to window.onload, or use a library that provides onDomReady (in jQuery, $(document).ready(function () ... });

var selectElement = document.getElementById('boro');

var showBoroSelect = function () {

    // find the selected element
    var selectedOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].id,

        // find the element that will contain the new drop down
        containerElement = document.getElementById('empty2fill'),

        // define the html for the manhattan drop down
        manhSelectInnerHTML = '<select name="secondary"><option value="derp">manh derp?</option><option value="herp!">manh herp!</option></select>',

        // define the html for the brooklyn drown down
        brookSelectInnerHTML = '<select name="secondary"><option value="derp">brook derp?</option><option value="herp!">brook herp!</option></select>',
        newInnerHTML;

    // determine which html to use based on the selection
    if (selectedOption === 'manh') {
        newInnerHTML = manhSelectInnerHTML;
    } else if (selectedOption === 'brook') {
        newInnerHTML = brookSelectInnerHTML;
    } else {
        // no boro was selected, hide the menu
        newInnerHTML = '';
    }

    // set the container to the new innerHTML
    containerElement.innerHTML = newInnerHTML;
};

// when the boro select changes, show the new menu
selectElement.onchange = function () {
    showBoroSelect();
};

// if you select a boro and reload the page, the boro may already be selected (for example, firefox might do this)
// this will set the boro menu initially before the user changes it
showBoroSelect();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
<select name="boro" id="boro" onchange="valBoro(this)">
    <option value="manhattan" id="manh">Manhattan</option>
    <option value="brooklyn" id="brook">Brooklyn</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
function valBoro(dropDown) {
    if (dropDown.options.[dropDown.selectedIndex].value.equals("manhattan")) document.getElementById('empty2fill').innerHTML = "newHTMLCode";
    //change "manhattan" to whatever option you want to use
}
</script>
```

Comment: hello there FireS. thank you for your reply. i copy/pasted and i got an error. says "missing name after . operator " not sure what that means.

Comment: @somdow I know you already accepted an answer, but what line is the error occuring on?

Comment: hey fire, sorry for long response. i just gave my friend the code and deleted it lol...but so i copy pasted and the js error i get is on the if(dropdown.options) etc... all it says is syntax error in Aptana, in DW the same thing